# How to deploy puma with nginx

Tags: deployment, puma

How to deploy puma with *nginx* or *apache*, is this possible or it's not necessary to use a web server like nginx or apache. What is the best way to deploy an app with **puma**?

Comment: are you asking how to declare puma as an upstream in the nginx configuration? How do you plan on using nginx? For caching? For load balancing?

Comment: Here is the detailed step by step guide:
http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/

Comment: Any reason you want you use Puma instead of [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com)? Phusion Passenger makes deployment a lot easier and with less configuration. You can get things up and running in minutes and you only need to configure Apache or Nginx, not any other components. Phusion Passenger is very mature, stable and performant and used by the likes of New York Times, Symantec, AirBnB, etc.

Comment: Yes I use Passenger but there are very interesting things about PUMA especially if you want to make real time applications

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the nginx conf for the site.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

}
```

As you can see `proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;` line tells nginx to listen to localhost at port **4000** you can change that to your needs.

This is a small change to work with ssl letsencrypt, of course you should configure ssl with letsencrypt.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Puma is not designed to be accessed by users directly, we will use Nginx as a reverse proxy that will buffer requests and responses between users and your Rails application. Puma uses threads, in addition to worker processes, to make more use of available CPU. Nginx and communication between puma is made through socket:

[image: nginx puma]

> Source Image : http://codeonhill.com

If you need explanation of how to deploy applications with Puma and Nginx checks [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)